# How modify this variable to 3 elements

Tags: sql, if-statement

i am using this variable to change the value in a field:

```
IF(IFnull(DATEDIFF(ADDDATE(IssuedDate, INTERVAL ExpirationTIme month),NOW()),datediff(ValidUntil,Now()))>0,'Active','Expired')
```

but my problem is that i need actually has 3 values, Active Expired and N/A,

N/A only will be show if ValidUntil is null

Maybe could be another way to do this..

any idea? thanksss in advance

Comment: ok so, how mus be look the code for 3 values  if want to use sql? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple if statement like the following:

```
IF(ValidUntil IS NULL, 'N/A', IF(IFnull(DATEDIFF(ADDDATE(IssuedDate, INTERVAL ExpirationTIme month),NOW()),datediff(ValidUntil,Now()))>0,'Active','Expired'))
```

Comment: Thanks Work perfect, hanks alot

Comment: There's a box near the answer to mark it as accepted answer, If it works for you mark it as accepted answer